# How would i ask to record in a place, in japan, politely

Tags: phrase-requests

Im going to be going to Japan and documenting my experiences in a vlog, is there any polite way to ask if im allowed to record. examples i can mostly think of are restaurants and stores. im aware of the signs outside of stores, and of blurring faces. i just want to properly learn how to ask

i cant find a proper way to ask this that is consistent between sources

*this is not a translation mods, nor is it a proof read*

Comment: `i just want to properly learn how to ask`, `this is not a translation mods` - One of these things is not like the other...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are not interested in learning the language(the vocabulary and the grammars), but just want a phrase that asks for permission to shoot videos nicely. As such, I will not explain on the grammar structure of the sentence or the usage of words. Just the sentence, here you go:

> Is it OK for me to take photos/videos here?
> ここで撮影してもよろしいですか？
> Kokode satsuei shitemo yoroshii desu ka?

That'll cover both photos and videos.